# Places autocomplete url returns nothing on querying through httpconnection in android

Tags: java, android, google-places-api

i am using the following code from the google documentation for getting the autocomplete places api for the android application. This code does not show any results in the dropdown on typing in the autocompletetextview.

```
class PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {
private ArrayList<String> resultList;
private static final String LOG_TAG = "Buzz";

private static final String PLACES_API_BASE = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place";
private static final String TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE = "/autocomplete";
private static final String OUT_JSON = "/json";

private static final String API_KEY = "AIzaSyCPrebeTr0lmiyjSwc1fdK82ZXLsmleSKc";

private ArrayList<String> autocomplete(String input) {
    ArrayList<String> resultList = null;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
        sb.append("?key=" + API_KEY);
        sb.append("&components=country:in");
        sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));
        sb.append("&types=(cities)&language=iw");

        Log.v(LOG_TAG,"URL for places: "+sb.toString());

        URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection)) 
        {
            Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Connection not created ");
        }

        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

        // Load the results into a StringBuilder
        int read;
        char[] buff = new char[1024];
        while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
            jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
            Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Value in input stream buffer: "+read);
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
        return resultList;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to Places API", e);
        return resultList;
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }

    try {
        // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
        JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");

        Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Predictions for given query: "+predsJsonArray.length());

        // Extract the Place descriptions from the results
        resultList = new ArrayList<String>(predsJsonArray.length());
        for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
            resultList.add(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));

            Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Results for the given url: "+predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot process JSON results", e);
    }

    return resultList;
}

public PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return resultList.size();
}

@Override
public String getItem(int index) {
    return resultList.get(index);
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {

    Filter filter = new Filter() 
    {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) 
        {
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            if (constraint != null) 
            {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Search string: "+constraint.toString());
                // Retrieve the autocomplete results.
                resultList = autocomplete(constraint.toString());

                // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                filterResults.values = resultList;
                filterResults.count = resultList.size();
            }
            return filterResults;
        }
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) 
        {
            if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
       };
    return filter;
}
```

}

This `in.read(buff)` code returns **157**,  what can be done for getting the autocomplete for the entered query

Comment: Try to use something like this: `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");sb.append("location=" + lat + "," + lon);sb.append("&radius=" + Startingvalue + "100"); sb.append("&types=" + "hospital");sb.append("&key=KEY");sb.append("&sensor=true");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you get the expected response in a browser?  I get `"status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"` when I use your values, but possibly you have set allowed IPs for the server/browser API key.

If you would like to use a library that provides a [GooglePlaceAutoComplete](https://pushbit.github.io/sprockets-android/apidocs/index.html?net/sf/sprockets/widget/GooglePlaceAutoComplete.html) widget, check out [Sprockets](https://github.com/pushbit/sprockets-android) (I'm the developer).  After setting it up with your API key, you could add a working Places API autocomplete to your layout with something like:

```
<net.sf.sprockets.widget.GooglePlaceAutoComplete
    xmlns:sprockets="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/place"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    sprockets:types="(cities)"
    sprockets:countries="IN"
    sprockets:language="iw"/>
```

Comment: i also got the ` "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED" ` with the generated url, Your solution seems a big one and I am a beginner in android. Could you please suggest some changes in this code so that i can use it.

Comment: Make sure that you're using a client or server key without any IP restrictions.  An Android key will not work with the Places API web service.